# Suppose A and B are sets. Prove that $A \subseteq B \implies (B - A) \cup A = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that:
$$A \subseteq B \implies (B - A) \cup A = B$$
Assume $A \subseteq B$.

($\implies$)Let $x\in (B - A) \cup A$.
$(x\in B \land x\notin A) \lor x\in A$
$\implies$ $(x\in A \lor x\in B) \land (x\in A \lor x\notin A)$
$\implies$ $(x\in A \lor x\in B) \land (T)$
$\implies$ $(x\in A \lor x\in B)$
$\implies$ $(x\in B \lor x\in B)$ [because $A \subseteq B$]
$\implies$ $x\in B$.

($\impliedby$)Let $x\in B$.

I am having trouble at this part of the problem. I'm not sure how to get from B to $(B - A) \cup A$.

Thanks.

Comment: The wording (or notation) is a little confusing.  You first line says you want to prove "$\implies$".  But your "case logic" seems to use implication in a different way.  Maybe you should label the cases $(\subseteq)$ and $(\supseteq)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . I'm not sure how to get from B to (B−A)∪A.

Recall $(x\in A\lor x\notin A)$ is $\top$.

Let $x\in B$.   Well also $(x\in A)$ or $(x\notin A)$, and so ...*yadda yadda yadda*... in either case $x\in(B\smallsetminus A)\cup A$.